# PHP close input channel of bidirectional stream from ssh2_exec()

Tags: php, stream, stdin, eof, libssh2

I have a bidirectional stream `$stream` returned from `ssh2_exec($command)`. The stream represents both the input and output of the command.

I can send input to the command with `fwrite($stream)` and I can read the command's output with `fread($stream)`.

I can check for the end of *output* with `feof($stream)`, but I have no way to tell the command about the end of *input*.

If I call `fclose($stream)`, the bidirectional stream is destroyed completely, and any following `fread($stream)` fails.

How can I do something like `fcloseinput($stream)` to close just the input part of the bidirectional stream?

Comment: Perhaps `fflush`, or writing EOT or some other control character?

Comment: My test case is the command `cat`. I've tried `fwrite( $stream, $data ); fflush( $stream );` and `fwrite( $stream, $data . "\x4" );` (\x4 being EOT) neither of which cause `cat` to stop waiting for input.

Comment: How about other control characters? You could loop through them all, and if one works, you just have to narrow it down.

Comment: I've tried every control character (ordinals 0 to 64) and none of them cause `cat` to stop reading input.

Comment: As a workaround, perhaps you could write to a temporary file on the remote server and just pipe that into the command you want?

Comment: I would like to avoid that.